# monitoring google app engine logs and send an email

Tags: google-app-engine

I am constantly monitoring the logs of my google app engine web app.

```
2012-03-27 14:37:27.842 /xyz.html 200 28ms 0kb
2012-03-27 14:34:42.581 /favicon.ico 200 50ms 0kb
2012-03-27 14:15:52.465 /img/ok-icon.png 200 102ms 0kb
2012-03-27 14:15:43.324 /favicon.ico 200 312ms 0kb
2012-03-27 14:13:51.777 /index.php?option=123 404 60ms 0kb
2012-03-27 13:55:23.178 /favicon.ico 200 1ms 0kb
2012-03-27 13:55:22.533 /img/testbkg.jpg 200 1ms 0kb
```

My question is: 
let's suppose that only rarely the url `/index.php?option=123` is hit.
and when that happens I want to know.

I'd love to be able to configure google app engine to send me an email when that happens.
It'd be sufficient if it just says: "hey go and check your logs"

Because I don't know how to do it what I end up doing is going to the google app engine dashboard and search my log (with the reg expression)

Is there a way of achieving this without writing a servlet to send an email ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several ways to do it:

1. Insert piece of code where you need it: in the file that is invoked when URL is called, e.g. in the `/index.php`.
2. Install servlet filter and check request URL and if this the request you are looking for.
3. Search through logs periodically via [`LogService`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/log/LogService). Use [cron](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron) to invoke search periodically.

Comment: Thanks for the many ways. But they all seem quite involved. Maybe I should have asked people to suggest the easiest way to achieve this (again ideally without writing any code)

Comment: @Zo72 I don't see why sending an email when that page is accessed (option 1) is involved - it's about as simple as you can ask for.